# Android Data Binding BindingAdapter: "Cannot find the setter"

Tags: android, android-databinding

This bound attribute is failing to build, with the error:

Cannot find the setter for attribute "errorText"

```
@BindingAdapter({"errorText"})
public static void setErrorText(TextInputLayout view, String error) {
    view.setError(error);
}


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorText="@{data.usernameError}"
        >
        ....
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: oh no data binding horror

Comment: maybe need to change this? @BindingAdapter({"usernameError"})

Comment: can you please upload whole xml file?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this error was being caused because the BindingAdapter was not being compiled, as a result of a source error elsewhere in completely unrelated code. That other source error (a typo so a variable being referred to was declared using a different name and so did not exist) was not clear in the build error log but once I saw it in the source code it was easy to fix and in turn fixed the BindingAdapter issue.

If you see this error, check for other possible build errors in the source and build logs.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `setErrorText` is public so you do NOT need define in `binding adapter`. 
It still works without define `errorText` in BindingAdapter class ( Confirmed ! )

If you want to define in binding adapter, you have to change as below:

`@BindingAdapter("app:errorText")`

Hopes this help !